# Can't use webcam on laptop

Tags: 14.04, webcam, acer

I am using Acer Aspire 5734Z-4725 model with ubuntu 14.04. The problem is I can't use the webcam. I use Cheese to test the webcam and it said "No device found".

I am new to ubuntu so a details instruction will be nice. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you know the model of the webcam try searching for a driver on their site, not sure if many providers do drivers for ubuntu.

Install UVC it might have your driver on it (http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#download)

If you cant remember the model id you can verify it by using `lsusb` in the terminal and verify that it is supported by UVC (http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices)

Comment: Doesn't work. My problem is with the build in camera on my laptop

Comment: what error do you get if you write cheese in the terminal? I've also read that there's a button that activates the camera? Fn+F10?

Comment: the laptop's camera is not found. I used it on window and everything is fine. Now after switching to Ubuntu 14.04, it doesn't work. I think it must be because of the driver but I don't know how to add driver for webcam

Comment: Well Acer do have a driver for your laptop which can be found here: (http://www.official-drivers.com/installer/?seed=acer&cate=webcam&gclid=CjwKEAjwheqgBRD5vOfR45az5AESJABy4m8-VCbQyV0eL3iuScdtkXcfIDCYyWEjdfTmWwLl9bPCmRoCD5Dw_wcB) but it is only for windows maybe use a windows computer to get the driver and copy it across?